# Winforms listbox listitems

Tags: winforms

```
public partial class Form1EOD : Form
{
    List<string> _items = new List<string>();
    public  int ItemHeight { get; set; }
    public Form1EOD()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AutoSizeMode= AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        listBox1.ItemHeight = 30;
    }

    private DataTable PSIDKey()
    {
        ASIDatabase dbconnection = new ASIDatabase(ASIDatabase._ConnectionType.Client);
        string query = string.Format(DigActionsQueries.GET_EOD_PSID, textBox1.Text);
        return dbconnection.getDataTableFromQuery(query);
    }

    public static DataTable Pivot(DataTable tbl)
    {
        var tblPivot = new DataTable();
        tblPivot.Columns.Add(tbl.Columns[0].ColumnName);
        for (int i = 1; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            tblPivot.Columns.Add(tbl.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i)));
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < tbl.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            var r = tblPivot.NewRow();
            r[0] = tbl.Columns[col].ToString();
            for (int j = 1; j < tbl.Rows.Count; j++)
                r[j] = tbl.Rows[j][col];
            tblPivot.Rows.Add(r);
        }
        return tblPivot;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text).Trim().Length <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please enter PSID KEY");
            return;
        }
        DataTable dr = PSIDKey();
        foreach (DataRow row in dr.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in dr.Columns)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(row[column].ToString()).Length > 0)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(column.ColumnName));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private string str = string.Empty;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text).Trim().Length <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please enter PSID Key");
            return;
        }

            for (int i = listBox1.SelectedIndex; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                {
                    string strdata = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
                    strdata = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();  
                    str = str + strdata + "=" + getFormattedValue("null") + ",";
                }
            }
            str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
            string query = "update asiAudit.dbo.EOD set " + str + " where EODPSID= " +
                           Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            ASIDatabase clientConnection = new ASIDatabase(ASIDatabase._ConnectionType.Client);
            clientConnection.insertDatafromQuery(query);
            MessageBox.Show("clear sucessfully");
            //listBox1.Items.Clear();
            //textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
        }

        private static string getFormattedValue(string val)
        {
            if (val == "null")
                return val;
            else
                return string.Format("'{0}'", val);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code for winform, 
when i hit the submit buton it will get the dynamnic columns to the listbox
and the clear button will clear the fields for the selected list item
my code works perfectly, but when i change my select query column names with aliases the update query doesn't works
This is my select query

```
public static string GET_EOD_PSID = @"select
      EODPlasticPrinted AS [Plastic Printed], 
      EODLaminate AS [Lamniate & Die Cut],
      EODEncoded AS [Encode], 
      EODHotStamped AS [Hot Stamp],
      EODEMVMilling AS [EMV Milling], 
      EODEmbossed AS [Embosing], 
      EODActivation AS [Activation Labels], 
      EODPlasticComplete AS [Final Count], 
      EODGVStaged AS [Match/Atach],
      EODGVComplete AS [Insertion], 
      EODAuditIn AS [Audit In],
      EODAuditComplete AS [Audit Out],
      EODAutoBagger AS [Autobaggeer],
      EODShippedIn AS [Shipped In],
      EODComplete AS [Complete]
    From
      asiAudit.dbo.EOD WITH(NoLock)
    WHERE 
       EODPSID in ({0})";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public partial class Form1EOD : Form
    {
        public Form1EOD()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private DataTable PSIDKey()
        {
            ASIDatabase dbconnection = new ASIDatabase(ASIDatabase._ConnectionType.Client);
            string query = string.Format(DigActionsQueries.GET_EOD_PSID, textBox1.Text);
            return dbconnection.getDataTableFromQuery(query);
        }
        public List<ItemType> ColumnsValues()
        {
            List<ItemType> columnlist = new List<ItemType>();
            columnlist.Add(new ItemType { ItemName = "EODPlasticPrinted", ItemValue = "Plastic Printed" });
            columnlist.Add(new ItemType { ItemName = "EODLaminate", ItemValue = "Laminate & Die Cut" });
            columnlist.Add(new ItemType { ItemName = "EODEncoded", ItemValue = "Encoder" });
            columnlist.Add(new ItemType { ItemName = "EODHotStamped", ItemValue = "Hot Stamp" });
            columnlist.Add(new ItemType { ItemName = "EODEMVMilling", ItemValue = "EMV Milling" });
            columnlist.Add(new ItemType { ItemName = "EODEmbossed", ItemValue = "Embossing" });
            columnlist.Add(new ItemType { ItemName = "EODActivation", ItemValue = "Activation Labels" });
            columnlist.Add(new ItemType { ItemName = "EODPlasticComplete", ItemValue = "Plastic Final Count" });
            columnlist.Add(new ItemType { ItemName = "EODGVStaged", ItemValue = "Match/Attach" });
            columnlist.Add(new ItemType { ItemName = "EODGVComplete", ItemValue = "Insertion" });
            columnlist.Add(new ItemType { ItemName = "EODAudiIn", ItemValue = "AuditIn" });
            columnlist.Add(new ItemType { ItemName = "EODAuditComplete", ItemValue = "AuditOut" });
            columnlist.Add(new ItemType { ItemName = "EODAutoBagger", ItemValue = "Autobagger" });
            columnlist.Add(new ItemType { ItemName = "EODShippedIn", ItemValue = "ShippedIn" });
            columnlist.Add(new ItemType { ItemName = "EODComplete", ItemValue = "Complete" });
            return columnlist;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text).Trim().Length <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please enter PSID KEY");
                return;
            }
            DataTable dr = PSIDKey();
            List<ItemType> dynList = new List<ItemType>();

            dynList = ColumnsValues();
            List<ItemType> itemlist = new List<ItemType>();
            foreach (DataRow row in dr.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dr.Columns)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToString(row[column].ToString()).Length > 0)
                    {
                        string columnvalue = column.ColumnName;
                        ItemType data = new ItemType(); 
                        data = dynList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ItemName == columnvalue);
                        itemlist.Add(data);
                    }
                }
            }
            itemlist = itemlist.Where(i => i != null).ToList();
            listBox1.DataSource = itemlist;
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "ItemValue";
            listBox1.ValueMember = "ItemName";
        }

        private string str = string.Empty;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text).Trim().Length <= 0) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please enter PSID Key");
                return;
            } 
            for (int i = listBox1.SelectedIndex; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            { 
                { var data = (ItemType)listBox1.Items[i]; 
                string strdata = data.ItemName;
                str = str + strdata + "=" + getFormattedValue("null") + ","; 
                } 
            } 
            str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1); 
            string query = "update asiAudit.dbo.EOD set " + str + " where EODPSID= " + Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); 
            ASIDatabase clientConnection = new ASIDatabase(ASIDatabase._ConnectionType.Client); 
            clientConnection.insertDatafromQuery(query); 
            MessageBox.Show("clear sucessfully");
           // listBox1.Items.Clear(); 
            textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
        }

        private static string getFormattedValue(string val)
        {
            if (val == "null")
                return val;
            else
                return string.Format("'{0}'", val);
        }
    }
    public class ItemType
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string ItemValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```